# How do you change the desktop theme in CentOS?

Tags: centos, desktop, theme

I have a couple of questions:

1. How do you change the desktop theme in CentOS?
2. How does one download CentOS themes from the internet?
3. How do you install them?

Comment: CentOS itself doesn't have themes. Be more specific.

Comment: Theme for what? Gnome? Boot screen?

Comment: @jordanm for Gnome

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is to install [gtk themes](http://gnome-look.org/) under `/usr/share/themes` or `/home/user_name/.themes` 
Then you can change gtk theme with [gtk-chtheme](http://pkgs.org/download/gtk-chtheme)

Comment: in tried under `/usr/share/themes`  - `yum install gtk-chtheme-0.3.1-11.el6.i686.rpm` but showing error like no package is available nothing to do

Comment: @user3021349 If exist this package under the Centos repos then just run `yum install gtk-chtheme` but If not exist then download [gtk-chtheme](http://pkgs.org/download/gtk-chtheme) after that run into the downloaded folder with root root user `yum localinstall gtk-chtheme-0.3.1-11.el6.i686.rpm`

Answer (score 2):

You can change your theme under this pull-down in CentOS:

> *System Settings* > *Advanced* > *Desktop Theme Details*

Much of the theming infrastructure for GNOME2 is gone, for example:  http://art.gnome.org/themes. But this site is still up and maintains icons, backgrounds, etc., for customizing your desktop.

- http://gnome-look.org/

**NOTE:** You'll want to focus on the [GTK2.x content](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/136/) on sites as your encounter anything that is listed as GNOME-specific.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of CentOS, I believe this is for 7.x and newer (I use CentOS 8.3), you can go to your software store and search tweaks then install GNOME tweaks, you will then be able to easily change to themes you have installed in your themes folder eg. */usr/share/themes*

In latest versions of CentOS there's no more System Settings > Advanced > there is only Settings with no advanced features. Also, gtk-chtheme is not available under CentOS repos, not even through epel repo.